# R total multiple columns at once with n()

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know if I am missing something very obvious here or not, but I am having trouble getting the desired results format for a count. These are all yes, no or NA answers to a question.

My data looks a bit like:

```
df <- read.table(text = " A  B  C
0   NA   1
1   0   NA
0   1   0
NA  NA  1
0   0   1
1   0   NA
0   1   NA  ", header = TRUE)

df %>%
group_by(A, B, C)%>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```

I have also tried

```
count(A, B, C)
```

with exactly the same results.

I want to count the total number of 0, 1 and NA responses for each column: (rows and columns are interchangeable here, it's the count of response v column format of the table that I'm after.)

```
Response 0 1 NA
Column A 4 2 1
Column B 3 2 2
Column C 1 3 3
```

What I am getting instead is

```
A  B  C  n
0  0  1  1
0  1  0  1
0  1  NA 1
0  NA 1  1 
1  0  NA 2
NA NA 1  1
```

In other words, it's counting the number of times each unique combination of ABC appears. How do I get it to focus on counting the columns and not the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it might need some data re-shaping if you want to use `dplyr::n()`.

First transform `df` into a "long" format, you'll get a two-column dataframe, from which we can group by everything (`group_by_all()`) and do your `summarize(n())`. Finally, transform it back to a "wide" format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Response") %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "value", values_from = "n")

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   Response [3]
  Response   `0`   `1`  `NA`
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
1 A            4     2     1
2 B            3     2     2
3 C            1     3     3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the `table()` function across the columns:

```r
df <- read.table(text = " A  B  C
0   NA   1
1   0   NA
0   1   0
NA  NA  1
0   0   1
1   0   NA
0   1   NA  ", header = TRUE)


t(apply(df, 2,table, useNA = "always"))
#>   0 1 <NA>
#> A 4 2    1
#> B 3 2    2
#> C 1 3    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

One alternate tidyverse solution would be the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = " A  B  C
0   NA   1
1   0   NA
0   1   0
NA  NA  1
0   0   1
1   0   NA
0   1   NA  ", header = TRUE)


x <- df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~fct_explicit_na(as.factor(.x),"NA"))) %>%
  map(., ~c(table(.x))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'Response') 

x
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Response   `0`   `1`  `NA`
#>   <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A            4     2     1
#> 2 B            3     2     2
#> 3 C            1     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `table` and `stack` you can try:

```
t(table(stack(df), useNA = "ifany"))
```

**Output**

```
   values
ind 0 1 <NA>
  A 4 2    1
  B 3 2    2
  C 1 3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself wanting to apply the same operation to multiple columns in your data it could be a hint that you should reshape your data to a "longer" format, such that each row represents a single observation. Once your data is in this format you can use `table()` to get the summary you're after:

```r
df_tidy <- 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "group", values_to = "response")

print(df_tidy)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 2
#>    group response
#>    <chr>    <int>
#>  1 A            0
#>  2 B           NA
#>  3 C            1
#>  4 A            1
#>  5 B            0
#>  6 C           NA
#>  7 A            0
#>  8 B            1
#>  9 C            0
#> 10 A           NA
#> # … with 11 more rows

table(df_tidy, useNA = "ifany")
#>      response
#> group 0 1 <NA>
#>     A 4 2    1
#>     B 3 2    2
#>     C 1 3    3
```